# Will my React Native app run on AndroidX?

Tags: android, react-native

I have built a React Native app using React Native 0.59.9 that works on my Android device that runs Android 9.x.

Even though there is a lot of information out there about migrating to AndroidX and React Native 0.60.x etc, I am finding it hard to find an answer to this (possibly) simple question - will my app run on AndroidX without changing any code? I have no support in my app or its packages for AndroidX.

Comment: AndroidX is not Android 10( or Q). If you don't make use of the libraries in androidX your app should work fine.

Comment: You may want to google Jetifier, it basically helps migrate packages to AndroidX APIs (even though it sounds like you don't currently need it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndroidX it's not a new operation system or new android version like android Oreo or Pie!

> AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library. Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature parity and new libraries

Actually it's more like new language for code for android.

For example you use *React Native 0.59.9* and i use *AndroidX* or *Old Android* to code android (it's not good example!)

So no worry about that! your codes works fine.

If you code with java or kotlin in android studio you need attention to androidX in *React Native* you don't need.

[source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems a big yes! if your android studio has it android x upgrade set. Means if your android studio is latest; the RN 0.60 migration code does seem to support it.  Why I am confident is that I have seen a log while building a fresh project to saying enabling jettifier and androix migration.

will update my answer later in the day with a screenshot and support link. I think there was a reddit thread on this topic too

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet ans is `YES`.
From react-native 0.60+ Android X is supported